# How to migrate core data model after I changed types for some attributes in some entities?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

Ok, I have 6 Entities: `WLComment`, `WLItem`, `WLPortal`, `WLSponsor`, `WLUser`, `WLWishlist`. Every of them has attribute: **identifier** of type **Integer 16**. Now I need to change the type for that attribute for EVERY entity to **Integer 32**.

- I know I need migration
- I know I **cannot** use lightweight migration because changing type is not allowed for that type of migration

This is how I setup core data stack in `AppDelegate.swift`:

`MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack()`

What should I do now?

Comment: Is the app released yet or is it still in development?

Comment: @Fogmeister App is released yet.

Comment: OK, well first off, you need to create a new version of the data model from the old version. Once the app is released you can't just change the model. It needs to remain the same. Then you create a new version which you make the changes to.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at a tutorial or something.

Comment: I have second version of core data. Do you have any tutorial for it?

Comment: The Ray Wenderlich site has a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Say the version of data model your already have is `Version 1`. I think you should:

1. create a new version of data model , say `Version 2`.  Set the arrtibute `identifier` to type Integer 16
2. set `Version 2` to the current model version
3. create a mapping model for `Version 1` to `Version 2`.
4. don't use `MagicalRecored.setupCoreDataStack()`. Instead, use `setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack()` instead.

Comment: It worked without mapping model. Can you explain me why? is it possible?

Comment: I didn't test it, but if it could work without a mapping model, it means Core Data is performing a lightweight migration, not a default one. Maybe Core Data could infer a mapping model automatically when you change the type from Interger 32 to Integer16